# APScheduler jobs not added to Heroku Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, apscheduler

I have an APScheduler background scheduler set up as such:

```
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

url = os.environ["DATABASE_URL"]
scheduler.add_jobstore(SQLAlchemyJobStore(url=url))

scheduler.start()
```

Every time I add a job, with the line:

```
scheduler.add_job(job, 'date', run_date=run_date, id=job_id)
```

it indicates that it occurred successfully. However, the jobs do not run and when I go to the Heroku Postgres console, and run

```
select * from apscheduler_jobs;
```

it indicates that no rows exist.

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer if you answered the question at https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/216

Comment: Sorry, I am still working on reverting the setup from production to development to test this.